# Windows 10 Default Browser as Chrome Does Not Work After Chrome Class Registry Fix

Tags: google-chrome, windows-registry, windows-10

Launching Chrome as default browser for links in Windows 10 doesn't work.

[image]

Setting any browser as default, including Edge and Internet Explorer, works.

This may be a side effect from the fact that I deleted the following entries according to [a very popular fix for the "Chrome class not registered"](https://superuser.com/questions/503489/chrome-doesnt-start-in-windows-8-gives-an-error-message-class-not-registered) error.

This question, might actually be **how to fix the above fix**... any ideas how I can restore those Chrome registry keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Google Chrome directly over this solved this issue including after doingn the class registry hack. Make sure to select "Set as default browser" at the [pre-download page](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html).