# Unable to set Chrome as default browser

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, file-association

Unable to set default browser to Chrome.

Neither from system side

[image]

not from Chrome side.

If I select Chrome in system settings, it just doesn't set. If I select to be default from Chrome, it opens the same system window.

Comment: You should be using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvlFN.png) method to set the default browser.

Comment: Related: [Windows 10 Default Browser as Chrome Does Not Work After Chrome Class Registry Fix](http://superuser.com/questions/957900/windows-10-default-browser-as-chrome-does-not-work-after-chrome-class-registry-f?rq=1) also Related: [How to set chrome as default browser Windows 10?](http://superuser.com/questions/1069346/how-to-set-chrome-as-default-browser-windows-10?rq=1)

Comment: I was able to set Chrome as my default browser without an issue on Windows 10.  So its possible the problem is your system configuration itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a different browser as your default first and see if it works. Then try launching chrome from administrator and set it as default in settings again if that doesn't help, try reinstalling chrome.

Comment: How lazy I turned! Had this idea, but decided to post SE first!